# SMS Banking Servers

Tags: mobile, sms, banking

what Hardware we use in order to implement an SMS Server to handle and receive SMS from clients for huge applications like a Mobile Banking Application ?

Answer (score 1):

For something really large, you would usually go talk to a telecommunications provider, and they would give you capacity on their network, and probably provide you with compatible hardware and such (for a hefty fee, of course).  You probably wouldn't just use something off-the-shelf without reference to the network environment.